# How to stop cursor from blinking

Tags: tty

How do I make the cursor stop `blinking` when in a **TTY**? (or anywhere else).

**BONUS Points** for one universal setting that stops the cursor blinking almost everywhere.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This gives you a solid yellow block (nonblinking) as a cursor:

```shell
echo -n -e '\e[?17;14;224c'
```

For more info check these references: [Linuxgazette](http://linuxgazette.net/137/anonymous.html) and [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CursorOnLinuxConsole) as well as the file `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/VGA-softcursor.txt` (if present on your system)

Comment: this works for me until i use vim, then when i exit the cursor is back to blinking :(

Comment: And this gives you a non-blinking solid white block `echo -e '\033[?16;0;224c'`

Comment: thx, I could change the last number (224) to 244 to get a solid **white** block :)

Comment: I have no effect of this on my system running bash 5.0.11 on Arch Linux

Answer (score 32):

There is a [**standard control sequence**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) to turn off cursor blinking on terminals.

```bash
printf '\033[?12l'
```

However many terminals do not implement this setting, so read on.

There is a more widely implemented standard terminal setting for switching **cursor visibility** between high visibility, normal visibility and invisibility. Some terminals don't make a difference between normal and high, and there's no guarantee that one or the other will or will not blink. In [terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html), emit the `cvvis`, `cnorm` or `civis` string (e.g. `tput cvvis`). The corresponding [termcap](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_node/termcap_35.html) entries are `vs`, `ve` and `vi`.

These setting will not survive a terminal **reset**, so you may find that it doesn't survive the launching of many full-screen applications. You can overcome this difficulty by adding the cursor configuration changing sequence to your terminal's reset string.

- On a terminfo-based system using ncurses, save your terminal's terminfo settings to a file with `infocmp >>~/etc/terminfo.txt`. Edit the description to change the `rs1` (basic reset) sequence, e.g. replace `rs1=\Ec` by `rs1=\Ec\E[?12l`. With some programs and settings, you may need to change the `rs2` (full reset) as well. Then compile the terminfo description with `tic ~/etc/terminfo.txt` (this writes under the directory `$TERMINFO`, or `~/.terminfo` if unset). Or more automatically:

  ```bash
  infocmp -1 | sed '/^.rs[12]=/ s/,$/\\E[?12l,/' | tic -
  ```
- On a termcap-based system, grab the termcap settings from your termcap database (typically `/etc/termcap`). Change the `is` (basic reset) and `rs` (full reset) sequences to append your settings, e.g. `:is=\Ec\E[?12l:`. Set the `TERMCAP` environment variable to the edited value (beginning and ending with `:`).

Some terminals and other applications give you more options:

- The [**xterm**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) cursor blinks if the `cursorBlink` resource is set to `true` or the `-bc` option is passed on the command line. The blink rate is customizable through the `cursorOnTime` and `cursorOffTime` resources.
- Some other GUI terminal emulators can blink the cursor; check their configuration dialog box.
- The [**Linux PC (VGA) console**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.html) has a number of cursor settings; their exact meaning and applicability depends on the underlying VGA implementation (Linux framebuffer or video card). If your default cursor blinks, try turning the hardware cursor off and the software cursor on with something like `printf '\033[17;127?c'` (the first parameter 17 gives you the software cursor without a hardware cursor, and the second parameter set to 127 makes it essentially inverse video). See above regarding terminal resets.
- In **Emacs**, `M-x blink-cursor-mode` toggles the cursor's blinking. Put `(blink-cursor-mode 0)` in your `~/.emacs` to turn it off. This is a global setting and does not apply in a text terminal.

See also [Juri Linkov **(Jurta)'s No Blinking page**](http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink) for how to turn off blinking in Lesstif, Tk, Gtk (Gnome), Qt (KDE), Firefox, and more.

Answer (score 20):

I found this to be easier if you have root permissions:

```
~$ echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

I put it in the machine startup script like `/etc/rc.local` for arch linux.

Comment: zsh: no such file or directory: /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink

Answer (score 9):

This hides completely the cursor.

```
tput civis
```

To restore:

```
tput cnorm
```

Answer (score 6):

In the linux tty you can use the escape sequence `"\e[?48;0;64c"` or whatever you like but this doesn't work in tmux/vim.

Tmux/Vim issue a `cnorm` command on startup which by default contains a `"\e[?0c"`. You can see that this undoes the effects of the above setting. You need to change `cnorm` to the above sequence in order for the TUI applications to reset the cursor to your preference.

More info on this by Gilles but if you are looking for a quick fix try this:

```bash
infocmp linux > /tmp/linux-terminfo
# Replace the last escape sequence here with your colors and settings
sed -i 's/cnorm=\\E\[?25h\\E\[?0c/cnorm=\\E[?25h\\E[?48;0;64c/' /tmp/linux-terminfo
tic /tmp/linux-terminfo
```

The last command will generate the new terminfo under `~/.terminfo` which should be picked up automatically if you restart tmux server/vim.

Answer (score 4):

Put

> \033[?17;0;127c

to your PS1 variable and you'll stop blinking constantly.

E.G:

> export PS1='\033[?17;0;127c\u:\w\$ '

Comment: This will (at least for me) screw up the terminal line breaks (on line overflow). Use square brackets, escaped: For example, `BLUEBOXNOBLINK="\033[?17;0;60c"`, then
`PS1="\[$BLUEBOXNOBLINK\]\[$BROWN\]\u \[$CYAN\]\W: \[$NC\]"`

Answer (score 2):

Works in gnome-terminal, Cygwin, etc.

**cursor.sh**

```bash
#! /bin/bash
case $1 in
    bb) echo -en '\e[1 q';; # blinking block
    nb) echo -en '\e[2 q';; # steady block
    bu) echo -en '\e[3 q';; # blinking underline
    nu) echo -en '\e[4 q';; # steady underline
    bv) echo -en '\e[5 q';; # blinking vertical bar
    nv) echo -en '\e[6 q';; # steady vertical bar
     *) echo -en '\e[0 q';; # default user-configured cursor 
esac
```

[Yes, the Space character is required.]

Source: [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences – Windows Console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#cursor-shape)
at Microsoft Docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo cp /etc/issue /etc/issue.tmp
setterm -cursor off | sudo tee /etc/issue
cat /etc/issue.tmp | sudo tee --append /etc/issue
sudo rm /etc/issue.tmp
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It is a wonderful solution and got probably a lot of upvotes, if the author didn't forget to explain it... :-)

Comment: `-cursor off` is not *quite* what is asked for at all, it makes the cursor disappear... `setterm -blink off` seems more promising, but it affects text, not the actual cursor.

Comment: `setterm -cursor off; setterm -cursor on` does work here, but it is an unacceptable workaround

Answer (score 0):

I put

```bash
echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

in `/etc/rc.local` and created a systemd service for it using online instructions. However, I noticed that sometimes after boot the cursor is still blinking. It would be good to know the correct way to permanently turn off cursor blinking via sysfs on a modern systemd system, does anyone have any tips? Some distributions have `/etc/sysfs.conf` but I am running Arch and don't find this file in sysfsutils or elsewhere.

As a temporary fix I ran the following command

```bash
sudo zsh -c 'echo -n "\033[?17;0;255c" >> /etc/issue'
```

Some experimentation showed that the `255c` at the end works better than `127c` listed above, it produces a white rather than grey cursor.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux console:

### Alternative 1

Add `-I "\033[?17;0;255c"` option to `getty` lines in your `/etc/inittab` file. To do so:

1. Open the `/etc/inittab` file with a text editor. There should be lines that contain `getty` or `agetty` or similar. An example is:

   ```
   tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
   ```
2. Add `-I "\033[?17;0;255c"` to each `getty` line. As an example, after adding `-I "\033[?17;0;255c"`, the `getty` line above would look as follows:

   ```
   tty1::respawn:/sbin/getty -I "\033[?17;0;255c" 38400 tty1
   ```
3. Reboot the system, or alternatively, kill all `getty` processes.

### Alternative 2

A better alternative is to put `ESC[?17;0;255c` in `/etc/issue`, instead of putting it to `getty` lines. Doing this using `vi` is as follows:

1. Open `/etc/issue` using `vi`.
2. On anywhere of the `/etc/issue` file, enter insert mode.
3. While you are in insert mode, press `^V` (that is, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>), then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. The escape character should now be inserted.
4. Now, insert the remaining characters, which are `[?17;0;255c`.

### Alternative 3

Another alternative is keeping the hardware cursor (instead of using a software cursor) and stop blinking of the hardware cursor and make it a block cursor. To do so:

1. Add the following to `/etc/inittab`:

   ```
   # Stop cursor blink on Linux console
   ::sysinit:/bin/sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink"
   ```
2. Add `ESC[?8c` to `/etc/issue`. Refer to "Alternative 2" for instructions on doing this.

However, with this option, the cursor does not become bright white. I guess this is only possible with using the software cursor.

After following any of these alternatives, you will obtain a white, non-blinking, block cursor.

[Further information](https://kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/vga-softcursor.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with the tty blinking cursor too. After looking in various places I eventually found this on [GitHub](https://github.com/atweiden/tty-no-cursor-blink). The cursor has stopped blinking in tty now.

Comment: Please consider explaining or at least summarizing the necessary steps to make this work on the target machine.