# Debian "sid"/Gnome: bash + browser cursor blink

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-terminal, cursor, iceweasel

I'm struggling to make the cursor in bash stop blinking. Also, the cursor in Iceweasel has started blinking again, but, for some reason, a lot slower than in bash :) I got those problems since I upgraded to sid, so probably some configuration files were overwritten.

I tried everything in [How to stop cursor from blinking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-to-stop-cursor-from-blinking) - nothing worked, probably because that was about tty, not bash.

This did not work (that is, setting the flags worked, just didn't do anything to the cursors):

```
gconftool --search-key cursor_blink
 /desktop/gnome/interface/cursor_blink = false
 /schemas/desktop/gnome/interface/cursor_blink = false
```

This did work, but only to make the cursor visible and invisible, it didn't stop the blink:

```
tput cvvis
```

This did not work:

```
echo -n -e '\e[?17;14;224c'
printf '\033[?12l'
```

My PS1 looks like this (added `\033[?17;0;127c`):

```
PS1="\033[?17;0;127c\\[$(tput setaf 3)\\]\u \\[$(tput setaf 4)\\]\w: \\[$(tput sgr0)\\]"
```

This is already set to zero:

```
/sys/class/graphics/fbcon/cursor_blink
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: `bash` has no say over cursor blink; it's up to the terminal emulator you're using.  If sid is running GNOME 3 like wheezy is, the configuration is in `dconf` instead of `gconf`; I don't know what the new settings would be off the top of my head, though.

Comment: OK! I don't have dconf, and aptitude cannot install it because dpkg complains it cannot find ldconfig and start-stop-daemon. Those are unfamiliar to me, but an aptitude search did not show any results. Speaking of GNOME 3, do you know how to check what version I'm running?

Comment: If you're logged in, `ps -fu$USER | grep gnome-shell`.  Although that's imperfect as you could be in fallback mode, and as far as I've been able to determine GNOME ignores all its settings in that case.

Comment: There is no gnome-shell line but a gnome-terminal that looks like this: incal     2997     1  0 12:03 ?        00:00:04 gnome-terminal - Is that what you meant? You lost me :)

Comment: No; `gnome-shell` is the fancy new GNOME 3 UI manager, replacing `gnome-panel` and a number of other independent programs used by GNOME 2.  I don't know how to detect fallback mode, though — it looks like GNOME 2 except it seems to ignore settings.

Comment: I managed to install dconf. I didn't understand how to use it, so I installed dconf-tools instead. This uninstalled dconf. Then, with dconf-editor I navigated to org.gnome.desktop.interface where I was very happy to see that cursor-blink was indeed checked. But, disabling it didn't help out. Maybe it didn't work, because that is a GNOME 3 tool, and I'm on GNOME 2? Anyway, I mentioned earlier that aptitude didn't work: I solved that by editing my sudoers file, as they talk about here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=390742 Also thanks for your efforts geekosaur

Comment: I apparently managed to confuse you; if `gnome-shell` was not running then you did not want or need `dconf`.

Comment: OK! I removed dconf-tools and installed gnome-panel. Now it works! But everything looks completely different and it is *slow as quicksand* so I guess I got a lot of extras to go with it. Wow, that was some cursor blink fix!