# Printing a sequence of square brackets in `gnome-terminal` is very slow

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

## Problem

I coincidentally was trying to print a string to `STDOUT` in `gnome-terminal` that contains a lot of square brackets and noticed it took a lot of IO time (~4sec for ~100KB). To confirm that there is something specific about that string, I printed another string of the length, and the time is very different.

Specifically:

```
$ time cat file1
# ... snip ...
real    0m3.968s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.001s

$ time cat file2
# ... snip ...
real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.006s
sys 0m0.001s

$ ls -l file*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sinan sinan 115441 Dec 19 16:38 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sinan sinan 115441 Dec 19 16:38 file2
```

- `file1`: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/060c3b2d
- `file2`: https://pastebin.pl/view/raw/ffbdd6a4

**I cannot tell what is the cause of the slowdown**, I suspect something in `gnome-terminal` parses square brackets and gives them a special meaning. Does anyone have any idea?

## Version Information

- `gnome-terminal --version`: `GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 using VTE 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD`
- `bash --version`: `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: My guess is that bash performs a lot of tests ( test == [ ), which take some time -- see here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/test

Comment: @AndreWildberg I doubt it. The shell should not interact with the data that is outputted by `cat`. However, the _terminal_ might be interested in doing syntax highligting or something similar.

Comment: I tried the first file in my gnome-terminal and it works instantly. Gnome-terminal version 3.28.2, bash 4.4.20, Ubuntu 18.04.05 64bit. Same in xfce4-terminal.

Comment: See the bash variable `PS1` which is the prompt. There are square-brackets e.g. for changing the title of the terminal and so on.

Comment: Filed upstream issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/343

Comment: A workaround is to disable bidi, either using `printf "\e[8l"` (lasts up to a `reset` or so, you might want to embed it in your prompt), or globally as a hidden gnome-terminal setting, by navigating `dconf-editor` to `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<the-profile-ID>/enable-bidi`.

Comment: Observed again: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674773/why-does-gnome-terminal-lag-when-using-brackets-or-parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Egmont [reported the bug on the vte bug tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/issues/343) (vte is a terminal emulator library used by gnome-terminal, anjuta, deepin-terminal, gtkterm, lilyterm, lxterminal, mate-terminal, remmina, sakura, tilda, vinagre, xfce4-terminal, …). It turned out to be [a bug in the underlying fribidi library](https://github.com/fribidi/fribidi/issues/163), which is unfixed as of October 2021.

#### Workaround: disable bidirectional support

Egmont also [suggests a workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625279/printing-a-sequence-of-square-brackets-in-gnome-terminal-is-very-slow#comment1201692_625279) which is to disable bidirectional support. Obviously, that workaround only helps if you don't care about bidi support.

For Gnome-terminal, you can do it via a hidden setting which has to be applied to each profile. The following command does this permanently for your account:

```
for p in $(dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/); do dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/${p%/}/enable-bidi false; done
```

For any vte-using terminal, you can disable bidi support temporarily with

```
printf '\e[8l'
```

but this only lasts until the terminal is reset. If you put this in your shell prompt, it'll help in command line applications, but not in full-screen applications. In bash:

```
PS1='\[\e[8l\]'$PS1
```

In zsh:

```
PS1='%{\e[8l%}'$PS1
```

A more general terminal-independent way to effectively disable bidi support is to change the terminal's reset sequence to include `\e[8l`. The terminal name (value of `$TERM`) in vte is `xterm-256color`. See [How to stop cursor from blinking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-to-stop-cursor-from-blinking/3769#3769) for explanations. This command will only affect new terminals, not ones that are already open.

```
TERM=xterm-256color infocmp -1 | sed '/^.rs[12]=/ s/,$/\\E[8l,/' | tic -
```